# angular2 @Input EventEmitter update view

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

iam trying to make a simple grid component and i have a trouble with updating view after emitting event !
Please explain who knows, why after updating simple component, view do not re-rendered ? whats wrong with this code ?

```
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() resource: any [];
  @Output() saveModel = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() deleteModel = new EventEmitter();
  attributes: any[];
  isUpdating: boolean = false;
  updatingID: number;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.attributes = Object.keys(this.resource[0]);
  }

  toggleUpdate(id, flag = true) {
    this.isUpdating = !this.isUpdating;
    this.updatingID = flag ? id : undefined;
  }

  destroy(id) {
    this.deleteModel.emit(id);
  }

  save(model) {
    this.saveModel.emit(model);
    this.toggleUpdate(model.id, false);
  }

  cancel(id) {
    this.toggleUpdate(id, false);
  }

}
```

Full example here https://plnkr.co/edit/InxsHu9GwCtMplYoocsS?p=preview

Comment: What is the expected behavior? What steps are required to reproduce the problem?

Comment: i have an array of objects and in grid component, just *ngFor directive loops over this array, and second *ngFor loops over object with custom pipe. GridComponent has @Output destroy and save. When update button clicked, instead of data component shows inputs with current values of model, and bind them with model. Save method trigger event and parent component listen for that event, and new data passed correctly, next i replace with a new array, but on the screen the same data. I tried implement ngOnChanges event and assign to this.resource =  values.resource.currentValue, without success

Answer (score 1):

The `resource` data is updated properly in parent and child components, just the form doesn't show the update.

I think you need to change the `values` pipe to only return the keys but not the values and then access the values using the `*ngFor` variables with the keys to get the values in the view directly.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**
Günter Zöchbauer, thank you saved my  time !

I think you need to change the values pipe to only return the keys but not the values and then access the values using the *ngFor variables with the keys to get the values in the view directly.

this was root of evil